# Old cartoon about a robot looked like a small girl

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

The young boy with his father arrive in a spaceship to some planet, maybe Earth, where to be a robot or a cyborg is illegal for some reason, the police arrests all robots and cyborgs. The boy finds a little girl which doesn`t remember who she is, he helps her and slowly she starts to remember, eventually it appears to them that the girl is a very advanced cyborg. The girl wants to return to her home, but it is very dangerous for her to be outside. The boy helps her to find her home while hiding from the police, at home the girl finally remembers everything, she is super robot which should to destroy everything, she starts her mission, but in the last moment fails and is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I found it - "[Metropolis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0293416/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2)" 2001